# Error with weblogic upgrade from 10.3 to 12.1.1

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, java-6, weblogic-10.x, jrockit

I'm trying to upgrade weblogic 10.3 to 12.1.1 but I'm receiving the following error, could someone have an idea about this? I am not very clear about the error.

[image]

I tried to upgrade first to 10.3.6 and I receive the same error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct upgrade from 10.x to 12c is not possible. You have to first upgrade to 10.3.x and then from 10.3.x to 12c.
See this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLUPG/intro.htm#WLUPG460) for details.
The 12.1.1 version is out of date, you should consider upgrading to 12.2.1.4 or 14.1.1 instead.

Comment: does 12.2.1.4 or 14.1.1 support Java 6??

Comment: no
12.2.1.4 : 7 & 8
14.1.1 : 8 & 11

Comment: I need to use 12.1.1 because it supports java 6. 

I'm trying first to upgrade to 10.3.6 as you told me, but I receive the same error.( I have uploaded the screenshot)

Comment: I think you have to upgrade first to 10.3.2 and then to 10.3.6 and then to 12.1

Comment: do you know where can I download that version? I have tried, buy I could not find it.

Comment: These very old versions are no longer available for download. May be you will have a chance with My Oracle Support.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem, as Emmanuel told me, I needed to install another version, I could find an installer to upgrade to 10.3.6, then I could install the version 12.1.1

Comment: Hi, You don't need to write this feed back as an answer. Answers is only for `answering the question`. If your answer has no additional information it will be down voted.